# Zap fails to parse OpenApi definition LongProperty cannot be cast to RefProperty, what does that mean?

Tags: security, swagger, openapi, penetration-testing, zap

I am importing a swagger OpenApi v2 export .json with full endpoint descriptions. I am importing this in ZAP to scan api endpoints. I am using the ZAP OpenApi importer.

The problem is I am getting this error:

```
io.swagger.models.properties.LongProperty cannot be cast to io.swagger.models.properties.RefProperty.
```

What does that mean? I am sure you can't probably solve this for me, but I have no idea what to even do next.

Comment: I'm thinking it's related to "$ref":"#/definitions/Some.Path.Here" having Dots.Between.Words and it thinking it's a long...

Comment: Got rid of the Dots.Between.Words - same problem.

Comment: Getting closer! I just replaced all instances of int64 to int32. And got "integerProperty" cannot be case to "RefProperty".

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with C# nullable int types?

Comment: Was your swagger definition generated or built by hand? If you're able to provide a sample I'm sure we could handle the condition with at least some better messaging. https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/new/choose It looks like the library used to do the parsing is having the issue which is kind of out of our control, however, we could at least probably provide some more specific feedback to the user.

Comment: It is generated. Sadly I cannot send it to you as a whole, but I can mask some parts of it and then send those. Which parts? This is a C# REST API, .NET Core 2.0. Was I correct that it's the nullable types? I tried to add the nullable=true for OAS 3.0, but the import from OAS 3.0 is not yet supported by ZAP.

Comment: Sure if you can strip it down to just one endpoint that fails and anonymize/obfuscate anything that might be sensitive or proprietary that's fine too, as long as we have a similar failure scenario then we have something to work from. My use of the OpenAPI addon has been pretty minimal thus far so I don't know if nullable types are an issue. As for OAS 3.0 support there's an existing ticket: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/4549

Comment: The endpoint file is absolutely massive, and there are tons of data there. And I don't even understand the format well enough. However, I'll try to do that and then message you. Might be after some while and OAS 3.0 could fix it by itself.

Thank you very much! :)